# Linq to XML - Null Reference Exception when using linq query.n

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConvenioValidacao>
    <convenio ven_codigo="1" tipoValidacao="CPF"></convenio>
    <convenio ven_codigo="1" tipoValidacao="MATRICULA"></convenio>
    <convenio ven_codigo="3" tipoValidacao="CPF"></convenio>
    <convenio ven_codigo="4" tipoValidacao="CPF"></convenio>
</ConvenioValidacao>
```

I'm trying to do a *simple* query against this xml file using **Linq to XML**, here is what i'm doing:

```
var myXmlDoc = XElement.Load(filePath);
var result =  from convenio in myXmlDoc.Element("ConvenioValidacao").Elements("convenio")
                 where (string)convenio.Attribute("ven_codigo") == "1" &&
                 (string)convenio.Attribute("tipoValidacao") == "CPF"
                 select convenio;
```

It is not working, I'm getting null reference exception.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var result = from convenio in myXmlDoc.Elements("convenio")
                 where (string)convenio.Attribute("ven_codigo") == "1" &&
                 (string)convenio.Attribute("tipoValidacao") == "CPF"
                 select convenio;
```

Since `myXmlDoc` is of type [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) there is no "document element" and as such the root of the element *is* the root node (`<ConveioValidacao>`).  Since this is the root node you don't need to specify it in an `Elements` method since that is current position in document.

As a side note, I recommend that you rename `myXmlDoc` to `myXmlElement` to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1):

.Element method gets first child element of the given element, in here ConveioValidacao is not a child element, it is the parent element, when you load by XEelemnt.Load() method it gets ConveioValidacao and it's child elements, so u should use Andrew's code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Descendants instead of Elements

```
var result =  from convenio in myXmlDoc.Descendants("ConveioValidacao").Descendants("convenio")
                 where (string)convenio.Attribute("ven_codigo") == "1" &&
                 (string)convenio.Attribute("tipoValidacao") == "CPF"
                 select convenio;
```

Comment: That stops it from throwing an exception but it doesn't solve the problem.  `myXmlDoc` is an `XElement` not an `XDocument` which means that the `<ConveioValidacao>` node is not a descendant of it.